# Angular / DataTables: TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined with 2 API calls

Tags: angular, datatable, rxjs, angular-datatables, rxjs-subscriptions

I've spent several hours trying to sort this issue out and I cannot find an answer that fits my case.

### Issue

I want to display in a DataTable data composed using two API calls. Those calls are performed in a service and the data is then emitted as subject. The component subscribed to the subject then displays the data in a datatable.

The problem is that the datable doesn't show up and I have an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`. This problem didn't happen when my data source came from a single API call and I suspect my concern is that the datatable is trying to instantiate itself before the data is loaded. I can fix the issue with an `*ngFor` by I have other kinds of bug, and I'd rather not do it like this.

---

> In short, my question is: **What am I doing wrong?**

---

### Code

Here is a simplified version of my code

`api.service.ts`

```js
import {Subject, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
...

export class APIService implements OnDestroy {
  // first data to be retrieved
  private data1: data1Structure;
  data1Subject = new Subject<data1Structure>();
  data1Subscription: Subscription;

  // second data to be retrieved
  private data2: data2Structure[];
  data2Subject = new Subject<data2Structure[]>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  emitData1Subject(){
    this.data1Subject.next(this.data1);
  }

  getData1() {
    this.http
      .get(`${this.baseURL}data1.json`)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.data1Source = response;
          this.emitData1Subject();
        },
        (error) => { console.log(error); }
      );
  }

  emitData2Subject(){
    this.data2Subject.next(this.data2.slice());
  }

  getData2(){
    this.data1Subject.subscribe((data) => {
      this.data1 = data;
      this.http
        .get(`${this.baseURL}data2.json`)
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            // Combine the two datasets
            this.data2 = this.formatData2(response);
            this.emitData2Subject();
          },
          (error) => { console.log(error); }
        );
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

`datatable.component.ts`

```js
import {ApiService} from '../../../services/api.service';
...

export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  data2Subscription: Subscription;
  colSettings = [
    {title: '#', data: 'Hid', width: '5%', visible: false},
    {title: 'Date', data: 'date', width: '45%'},
    {title: 'Title', data: 'title', width: '50%'}
  ];
  dtTrigger: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    // first API call
    this.apiService.getData1();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // second API call
    this.apiService.getData2();
    this.data2Subscription = this.apiService.data2Subject.subscribe(
      (data2) => {
        this.dtOptions = this.dataTable.getTableSettings(data2, this.colSettings);
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      },
      (error) => { console.log(error); }
    );
  }

  getTableSettings(records, colSettings: DataTables.ColumnSettings[]): DataTables.Settings {
    return {
      data: records,
      columns: colSettings,
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 50,
      deferRender: true,
      dom: 'lBfrtip'
    };
  }
}
```

`datatable.component.html`

```html
<table id="data2" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtWTrigger" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

#### Environment

```
Angular version: 9.1.1
Datatables version: 9.0.2
Chrome / Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5
```

I hope my question isn't too confusing, I really can't figure out what to do to fix this problem...

Thank you very much for your help!

***Edit***: fix indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you change the way you're making your requests and merge them together in a single Observable. Seeing as you are consuming the results of your HTTP requests in your template, the best practice is to use the `async` pipe with the final merged Observable:

```js
compiledData$: Observable<CombinedDataObjectType>; // create a custom type here

ngOnInit() {
  this.compiledData$ = this.http.get('firstUrl').pipe(
    switchMap(firstData => this.http.get('secondUrl').pipe(
      map(secondData => ({ firstData, secondData }))
    )),
  );
}
```

Your Observable now emits an Object containing both sets of data, so in the template:

```html
<div *ngIf="compiledData$ | async as data">
  <!-- Consume data here -->
</div>
```

Basically, avoid putting logic in `subscribe` callbacks, and in fact avoid subscribing in TS wherever possible. There is almost always a more elegant, more performant, easier maintained way to do things!